Unsloth save_pretrained_gguf FAILED. RuntimeError: Failed compiling llama.cpp. Please report this ASAP
Using unsloth and trying to save the model as gguf I am getting this error:
-> 1052 if check != 0: raise RuntimeError("Failed compiling llama.cpp. Please report this ASAP!")
   1053 check = os.system("rm -rf llama.cpp/build")
   1054 if check != 0: raise RuntimeError("Failed compiling llama.cpp. Please report this ASAP!")

RuntimeError: Failed compiling llama.cpp. Please report this ASAP!

I have seen there is an issue about this topic. Someone has some news or some alternative solutions?
